# Vue composition api - composable with global state that uses component props

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

In my app there is a composable called `useLocalization`. It provides translated strings based on the user's language preferences, and is used throughout the app.

The problem is, that `useLocalization` can be configured, and accepts the following arguments, but I don't know what the best way of passing these arguments from the root component to the composable:

```js
 interface ILocalizationProps {
    currentLocale: Ref<string>
    fallbackLocale: Ref<string>
    locales: Ref<Partial<ILocale>[]>
  }
```

The root component that uses `useLocalization` accepts the same arguments as `props`, so the consuming App can configure/override the language used.

```js
const DEFAULT_LANG = 'en'
export const withLocalizationProps = () => ({
    currentLocale: { type: String, default: null },
    fallbackLocale: { type: String, default: DEFAULT_LANG },
    locales: { type: Array as () => Partial<ILocale>[], default: () => [] },
})
```

How can I initialize my composable with the props passed to the root component? Here's what I tried/issues I found:

1. `useLocalization(props)` doesn't work here, as the props are not available deeper in the component tree.
2. Using `provide/inject` I can use `props` in the `provide` part, and get the correctly configured version with `inject`, but this prevents my from using `useLocalization` in the root component, as the injection is not available.
3. Use a hacky solution such as in [vee-validate / injectWithSelf](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/64d04f14590b79c8f8d4d936f941710b7566a3c6/packages/vee-validate/src/utils/common.ts#L144). Even then, The signature of the composable would be `useLocalization(props?: IProps)`, and my root component has to be the first one to call this function with the props.
4. Use a helper such as [createInjectionState](https://vueuse.org/shared/createinjectionstate/), but it's the same problem as 2.

Is there a *best way* to solve this? Composable that don't depend component state, such as [useMouse](https://vueuse.org/core/useMouse) work great, but (globally) configurable composables cause the afore mentioned issues :(

Comment: There's no best way. I keep the initialization and the usage separated, `setupLocalization` and `useLocalization`. If you need to use both in the same component, you may want to make use it with something like injectWithSelf. This may be XY problem as it's unknown why init data is in root props. If it were available on app init, setupLocalization could be written as regular Vue plugin, `Vue.use(localizationPlugin, {...initData...}`). This is how it's done most times.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, it'd be better to use provide/inject than using props.

Here's the reference.
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html